# wallet to exchange

Tags: transactions

when sending XTZ from wallet (tezbox) to an exchange, is there anything to consider adress-wise?
My funds are currently located at a KT1 adress, but the tezbox wallet also has a tz1 adress. From which adress should i send the tezos?

KT1 --> tz2 or
tz1 --> tz2?

Is there anything else to consider? Is it a problem that the KT1 adress has an active delegation?
Since this is not an everyday task for me and mistakes can result in a total loss i wanted to get your input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can send funds from KT or tz it does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Babylon upgrade, most exchanges are having difficulty processing a contract execution for transfer of funds. This would the case when doing KT1 -> exchange (tz1). To save yourself any headaches and worry, I would recommend that you first transfer from your KT1 back to your own tz1, and then from your tz1 to exchange.

Keep in mind that in order to transfer out of a KT1, the manager's tz1 must have at least 0.001xtz to pay for contract code execution.

TezBox is also not a well recommended web-wallet any longer. Most people on Reddit report have better success with Galleon or Kukai. You can restore your wallet from TezBox to either of these without worry as long as you have your original seed phrase.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and profound answer! 
When i want to switch to Galeon, i would just choose the option "import fundraiser wallet", right? Then my XTZ (from the ICO and the baking), that are currently stored in TezBox are transfered to Galeon?

Comment: Understand that absolutely NOTHING is "stored" in a specific wallet. Everything, everything, everything is stored "on the chain". A "wallet" simply lets you interact with the chain. You should be able to import to Galleon using whatever export methods are available from TezBox. When you do it correctly, everything in TezBox will appear in Galleon.

Comment: Also, please mark the above as answered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations!